# blackberry domain call not working from ajax

Tags: ajax, blackberry, cordova, cross-domain

my function is below and ajax.status is giving error 500  and responseText is blank first time and  responseText givies local connection timed out on 2nd and third state change can anyone tell me where the problem lies.

```
function go(){
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("post","http://abc.com", true);
ajax.send();
ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
alert("readysta="+ajax.readyState);//2//3//4
alert("status="+ajax.status);//500/500//500
alert("yoo="+ajax.responseText);//blank//local connection timedout  12000//localconnetiontimedout
}
```

my config.xml is

```
   <name>ugtytsd</name>
  <access subdomains="true" origin="*"/>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.system" /> 
 <rim:navigation mode="focus" />
```